# UploadString takes 60sec to post very short string

Tags: .net, webclient

I'm creating tests. My UDP test client sends a message to my UDP service. The payload is a JSON string. When it finds an attribute "ForwardingAddress" the UDP service does this:

```
WebClient.UploadString(forwardingAddress, payload)
```

All this works, but my mock webserver, implemented with a bare socket and a StreamReader wrapped around the stream obtained from the socket, takes exactly 60 seconds for ReadToEnd() to return.

This smells a lot like a timeout value. Does anyone know where this timeout can be set? Otherwise I'll be forced to replace ReadToEnd with a loop and string parsing state machine.

Comment: Kind of hard to say without seeing the server side. What happens if you use some other method to upload the string? Say, hitting it with a browser?

Comment: I am not into .net but my suggestion on general socket programming is closing the client side write stream (or EOF), so the "end" condition will be satisfied.

Comment: Which server do you want to see, Jim - UDP server or mock webserver? I'm happy to post fragments from either, but the UDP server code is a bit fragmented because it's all APM.

Comment: Now I feel silly: there's a class HttpListener which does exactly what I require. 338ms instead of 60sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a class HttpListener which implements the server side of the HTTP protocol.

Internally I daresay it contains a very complete implementation of the string parsing state machine I didn't want to write.

This is entirely proper - "TCP-IP" is a suite of protocols, of which FTP and HTTP are members. I'm very impressed with the completeness of this part of the framework. Most impressive, Microsoft.